# AngularJS : How to pass model data to service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is my controller

```
blogApp.controller('myController',
['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService)
{
    $scope.logIn = myService.loginUser($scope.checkUser);
};
}]);
```

This is my view

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="checkUser.username">
</div>
```

This is my service

```
blogApp.service('myService', function ($rootScope)
{    
   this.loginUser = function() {
   someAPI.logIn(checkUser.username);
 }
```

It is showing error that checkUser is not defined.

**Update**: I updated my service code as follows:

```
this.loginUser = function(checkUser) {
       someAPI.logIn(checkUser.username);
     }
```

It is still not working.

Comment: Almost that... it's $scope

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the function you call grab the parameter that you pass:

```
blogApp.service('myService', function ($rootScope)
{    
  this.loginUser = function(checkUser) {
    someAPI.logIn(checkUser.username);
  };
});
```

Comment: What do you mean, "not working?" Do you get an error message?

Comment: Ok I resolved it. I must define the checkUser in my controller like this.
$scope.checkUser = {};

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS is great in the fact that if you declare a `$scope` variable in your html but not in your controller it will instantiate it for you as an empty string.

However you have `$scope.checkUser` as an Object (which is not instantiated), I think that is where your problem lies.

---

**Try this**

Controller:

```
blogApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {

    $scope.checkUser = {};

    $scope.logIn = function () {
        myService.loginUser($scope.checkUser);
    };

}]);
```

Html:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="checkUser.username">
    <button ng-click="login()">Log In</button>
</div>
```

Service:

```
blogApp.service('myService', function () {    
    return {
        loginUser: function(checkUser) {
            someAPI.logIn(checkUser.username);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: Angular won't instantiate an empty string value in your $scope until the user interacts with the element on the HTML form. Angular will also create empty objects for you if they don't exist in your $scope when the user interacts with the HTML form. The values before user interaction are undefined -- if not declared explicitly in the controller (or elsewhere in code where $scope can be modified).

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the trick

```
// Service
blogApp.service("myService", function(){

    // Save the settings
    this.saveSettings= function(username){
         // Save your stuff here
    };
}
// in controller Controller
myService.saveSettings($scope.checkUser.username);
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.checkUser is not defined when your controller is initially created as it is bound to your input box, which the user hasn't had a chance to type into yet. In this case, Angular won't create the $scope.checkUser object for you (nor the username property) until the user keys into the textbox. If you were to add a click handler to your controller, that should do the trick:

```
blogApp.controller('myController',
['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    //make this a click handler
    $scope.logIn = function () {
       //Make sure the user typed something
       if ($scope.checkUser) {
           myService.loginUser($scope.checkUser);
       }
    }
}]);
```

And your view:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="checkUser.username">
    <button type="button" ng-click="logIn">Log In</button>
</div>
```